# Slicing of two dimensions in SystemVerilog

Tags: multidimensional-array, verilog, system-verilog

In SystemVerilog, I'm trying to do the following:

```
wire signed [0:95][0:4][0:4][31:0] X;

wire signed [0:31][0:31][31:0] Y;

assign X[0] = Y[0:4][0:4];

assign X[1] = Y[0:4][1:5];

assign X[2] = Y[1:5][0:4];

assign X[3] = Y[1:5][1:5];

...
```

The error:

```
Error-[SE] Syntax error
  Following verilog source has syntax error :
  "try.sv", 399: token is '[', column 53
                assign X[0] = Y[0:4][0:4];
```

Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SystemVerilog does not allow slices that represent non-contiguous regions of an array. You would have to do this with a `for` or `foreach` loop. I'm not exactly sure what your intentions are, but this should get you going.

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
     X[0][i][j] = Y[i][j];
```